# How to decode json file produced from curl in php

Tags: arrays, json, curl, decode, jsondecoder

At the end of my curl, as follows

```
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);
  
  curl_close($curl);
  
  if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  } else {
    echo $response;
  }
```

I get this

```
{ "status": true, "message": "Account number resolved", "data": { "account_number": "xxxxxxx", "account_name": "ONY xxxx xxxx", "bank_id": 21 } }
```

Now, I am trying to decode

Now I am trying to decode $responds and get the account_name as I tried this

```
var_dump($response);
$var = json_decode($response);

echo $data->account_number
```

But didn't work, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference `$var` before using `$data->account_number`:

```
<?php

$response= '{"status":true,"message":"Account number resolved","data":{"account_number":"xxxxxxx","account_name":"ONY xxxx xxxx","bank_id":21}}';

$var = json_decode($response);

echo($var->data->account_number); // prints xxxxxxx
```